# Every countably generated sigma algebra is generated by a random variable

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

Suppose I have a sigma algebra which is countably generated. I want to find a random variable such that it is generated by that random variable. If the countable class is just a single set then my random variable is indicator function. But, how to do in this case ? If we sum up all the indicators to define our random variable then the sum may diverge. How to make sure it converge ?

Comment: An induction prove should be easier (at least to follow) than the answer provided below.

Comment: @Zhanxiong I feel like we couldn’t use induction here because it involves infinity (in the case that the sigma algebra is countably generated). Mathematical induction only works for any finite step.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: Each $\mathbf 1_{A_n}$ is measurable with respect to $X=\sum\limits_k\frac1{3^k}\mathbf 1_{A_k}$.

Answer (score 6):

In the interests of completeness, we provide a complete solution.

**Lemma.** Let $X_1, X_2, \dots$ be a sequence of Bernoulli random variables $($not necessarily independent, not necessarily with same $p$-value$)$. Define$$Y = \sum_{i=1}^\infty {{2X_i}\over{3^i}}.$$Then $\sigma(Y) = \sigma(X_1, X_2, \dots)$.

*Proof.* Fix $n$, and consider the event $\{X_n \in I\}$, where $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ is an interval. If $I$ contains $0$ and $1$, then $\{X_n \in I\} = \Omega \in \sigma(Y)$. If $I$ contains neither $0$ nor $1$, then $\{X_n \in I\} = \emptyset \in \sigma(Y)$. If $I$ contains $1$, but not $0$, then $\{X_n \in I\} = \{X_n = 1\}$. This is the event that the $n$th digit in the ternary expansion of $Y$ is $2$, which occurs exactly when$$Y \in \bigcup_{k=1}^{3^{n-1}} \left[{k\over{3^{n-1}}} - {1\over{3^n}}, {k\over{3^{n-1}}}\right],$$which is a Borel set. Thus in this case, $\{X_n \in I\} \in \sigma(Y)$. If $I$ contains $0$, but not $1$, then $\{X_n \in I\} = \{X_n = 0\}$ and a similar argument to the preceding case shows $\{X_n \in I\} \in \sigma(Y)$. Since intervals generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$, it follows that $\sigma(X_1, X_2, \dots) \subset \sigma(Y)$.

Now, choose $x \in [0, 1]$ and write down a ternary expansion $x = 0.a_1a_2a_3\dots$. Then we have$$\{Y \ge x\} = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \left(\{2X_1 \le a_1\} \cap \{2x_2 \le a_2\} \cap \dots \cap \{2X_k > a_k\}\right) \in \sigma(X_1, X_2, \dots).$$Since the intervals $[x, \infty)$ generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$, it follows that $\sigma(Y) \subset \sigma(X_1, X_2, \dots)$.$\tag*{$\square$}$

Let $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a random variable. Recall that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ is countably generated; let $\{A_i\}$ be a countable generating collection for the Borel sets. It is an exercise left to the reader to show that every Borel set may be obtained by a sequence of countable unions and complementations of the $A_i$ $($alternatively, one can use the Dynkin $\pi$-$\lambda$ Theorem$)$. Since these operations are preserved under taking preimages, every event of the form $\{X \in B\}$, where $B$ is a Borel set, is included in $\sigma\left(X^{-1}(A_1), X^{-1}(A_2), \dots\right)$. Hence $\sigma(X)$ is countably generated, by the collection $\left\{X^{-1}(A_i)\right\}$.

Conversely, suppose $\mathcal{G}$ is countably generated, say by the collection $\{A_i\}$. For each $i \in \mathbb{N}$, define the random variable $X_i = \mathbb{1}_{A_i}$. Evidently, $\sigma(X_1, X_2, \dots) = \mathcal{G}$, since the event $\{X_i \in A_i\}$ is just $A_i$ for each $i \in \mathbb{N}$. Note that each $X_i$ is Bernoulli distributed, taking value $1$ with probability $P(A_i)$ and value $0$ with probability $1 - P(A_i)$. Thus, setting $Y = \sum(2X_i)/3^i$, the lemma implies that $\mathcal{G} = \sigma(Y)$.