# $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G} \subset \mathcal{F}$ is countably generated iff there is a random variable $X$ such that $\mathcal{G} = \sigma(X)$.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request

Where can I find a reference to the proof of the fact that a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G} \subset \mathcal{F}$ is countably generated if and only if there is a random variable $X$ such that $\mathcal{G} = \sigma(X)$? There is not a proof in Durrett's Probability: Theory and Examples, of which I am reading right now, and searching online, there doesn't seem to be a complete proof of this fundamental fact anywhere on this site either.

Comment: Take a look here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.3066.pdf (pages 12-13)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680500/every-countably-generated-sigma-algebra-is-generated-by-a-random-variable