# Countably generated sigma algebra vs. generated by a real-valued random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Dear StackExchange community

Given an arbitrary probability space ($\Omega, \Sigma, P$) (without a topological structure), is it true that for any countably generated sub sigma algebra there exists a real-valued random variable that generates it?

After researching this question, I came up with mixed results.

- I know there is this post
  [Every countably generated sigma algebra is generated by a random variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680500/every-countably-generated-sigma-algebra-is-generated-by-a-random-variable), but it seems to me that the proof makes implicit use of some topology on $\Omega$
- This text https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.3066.pdf (Prop. 3.2) states that a
  sigma algebra is countably generated iff it is generated by a mapping
  ($\Omega, \Sigma$) $\rightarrow$ ({$0,1$}$^\mathbb{N}$, Borel sigma
  algebra on {$0,1$}$^\mathbb{N}$), which is not the same as our usual real-valued random variable
  $(\Omega, \Sigma) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R},$ Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}$)

**Why this matters**: Several results on the existence of regular conditional probability make use of the condition "$\Sigma$ is countably generated". Life would have been much easier if we could replace this condition with "$\Sigma$ = $\sigma (X)$ for some real-valued random variable $X$" (because $\sigma (X)$ has some nice properties).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ is  a Polish space with the same cardinality as $\mathbb R$. Hence, there is a bijection  $f: \{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}  \to \mathbb  R$  such that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are measurable (for the Borel sigma algebras on both sides). Composing a $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$  valued measurable function with this $f$ gives the answer.

Reference for existence of $f$: Measure Theory by Cohn.